# How do I start PHP program?

Tags: php, html

So I'm writing a website that query's MySQL db and just returns what's in it in a table form.  This being my first time using PHP (I have read tutorials but can't find one where it explains this part) and when i launch the query that uses php it just opens another browser window that shows the php code only.  Not sure why its doing this, so thought maybe you guys can help.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert URL</title>
    <style type = "text/css">
        label { width: 5em; float: left; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post" action = "db_query.php">
        <div><label>URL: </label>
            <input type="text" name="URL"><br></div>
        <div><label>Description: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Description"></div>
        <p><input type = "submit" value = "Query"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Search Results</title>
<style type = "text/css">
     body  { font-family: sans-serif;
             background-color: lightyellow; } 
     table { background-color: lightblue; 
             border-collapse: collapse; 
             border: 1px solid gray; }
     td    { padding: 5px; }
     tr:nth-child(odd) {
             background-color: white; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php

        $db_connect = mysql_connect("192.168.0.1", "db", "password");
        $db_query = "SELECT * FROM urltable";

        if (!$db_connect)
        {
            die("Could not connect to database");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Connected to the Database!");
        }

     ?><!-- end PHP script -->

     <table>
     <caption>Results of "SELECT <?php print( "$db_query" ) ?> 
        FROM URLS"</caption>
     <?php
        // fetch each record in result set
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) )
        {
           // build table to display results
           print( "<tr>" );

           foreach ( $row as $value ) 
              print( "<td>$value</td>" );

           print( "</tr>" );
        } // end while
     ?><!-- end PHP script -->
  </table>
```

Ignore the two input boxes in the HTML code, they are just place holder for now.  Anyways when I hit the Query button it just opens a new browser that shows the php code and not the actual query.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Do you have a webserver like Apache running or are you calling the files directly from the filesystem? PHP code needs to be served by a webserver.

Comment: You have to install PHP on your server. Once php is installed, it will parse whatever is in <?php ?> and run that as php code.

Comment: By the way, since you are just getting started, do NOT user `MYSQLI`, it is deprecated.  Use either `MYSQLI` or `PDO`.

Comment: Sorry, typo (can't edit the previous comment) do not use `MYSQL`, use `MYSQLI` or `PDO` to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute PHP you are going to *need* a web server like Apache that will handle the requests for you.

You can take a look at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (Windows, Mac and Linux), [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (on Mac only) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (on Windows only) to run a local web server.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes sense.  I uploaded the php and my site to a remote server and now its giving me some feedback instead of just printing the code.

Comment: @Nick, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you is to install WAMP (on Windows) or MAMP (on MAC) or LAMP (on Linux).
After that put your script in C:\wamp\www (on Windows), make sure that WAMP server is started (there should be a green icon in the right button corner near to clock), open the web browser and type: `http://localhost/nameofyourscript.php`
You can also create folder in C:\wamp\www with your custom name (ex. myproject) and put your script in that folder.
Start the script on web browser: `http://localhost/myproject/nameofyourscript.php`